# Icons in custom dialogs android

Tags: android, dialog, icons

Is there a way to set an icon on a custom dialog without using the AlertDialog methods?
Dialog has title, but is missing that nice divider and the ability to set an icon, but surely there must be a way of getting both without having to use AlertDialog?

Answer (score 19):

You can add an icon with the following code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");

dialog.show();
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.your_icon);
```

For a divider you can simply add an `ImageView` to your dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dim_dark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Gubbei that doesnt seem to work either....i get a 01-24 04:46:24.037: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1693): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Did you call `requestWindowFeature()` **before** `setContentView()`?

Comment: Thanks Gubbel, works fine for me. Note: It is _not_ necessary to set the Drawable after the `show()`, which is nice, as normally the Dialog is created in `onCreateDialog()` whilest `show()` is called elsewhere.

Comment: But it is necessary to setFeatureDrawable below setContentView check out https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/G_5MAq8v4jc

Answer (score 2):

A nice way of adding a divider is by using a gradient shape.

Simply make a file `gradient.xml` or so, in your `res/drawable/` catalog and put something like this into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="#424542" 
          android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:endColor="#424542" 
          android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

And then inside your LinearLayout you can put a View:

```
<View android:id="@+id/divider" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dip"
      android:background="@drawable/gradient">
</View>
```

Then it paints a nice gradient divider :)