# How to set icon for dialog in Android

Tags: android

I want to customize a dialog in Android.
I know how to set the title for dialog:

```
dialog.setTitle("O message");
```

Now I want to set the icon in front of the title.
How can I achieve this?

```
Dialog dialog;
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layouterror22);      
dialog.setTitle("O message");
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add an icon with the following code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.your_icon); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");

dialog.show();
```

See ["Icons in custom dialogs android"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388674/1430996).

Comment: The order of the lines: it's very important as the features must be requested before any content is pushed to the dialog.

Comment: The order of the lines: it's very important!!! dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.your_icon); should be called after setContentView

Answer (score 10):

use this,

```
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

you need more customization means, refer this site http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/

Comment: this is Dialog don't AlertDialog

Comment: @user1497597: refer this link it has an example you can make change as yours http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Answer (score 5):

```
dialog.setIcon(Drawable icon);
```

or

```
dialog.setIcon(int resId);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i get dialog.setIcon but don't support (Note: this dialgo customize ) this is may code: Dialog dialog;  dialog = new Dialog(this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layouterror22); dialog.setTitle("O message");

Comment: Question is about Dialog, not AlertDialog.  The answer above is not applicable to Dialog.  See Carl Bosch comment above.

Answer (score 3):

May be you should use an AlertDialog. If you do, just

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourContext);
b.setIcon(yourIcon);
/* add other properties thanks to b.set... */
b.create().show();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i get dialog.setIcon but don't support (Note: this dialgo customize ) this is may code: Dialog dialog;  dialog = new Dialog(this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layouterror22); dialog.setTitle("O message");

Comment: `AlertDialog` seems to need `setTitle()` applied for `setIcon()` to work.

Comment: @jdv that was awesome.  I had just coded up my setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert) and was wondering why it wasn't working,  and I look on the other side of my screen and there's your comment explaining exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `viewPager` with fragments, you can call a `safeExit()` from the `onBackPressed()` of the `MainActivity`. This is what I have done, I've never had any problems:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        try {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0);
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            } else
                safeExit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void safeExit() {
        new Builder(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTitle("Exit!").setMessage(
                "Close Application?").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add icon to your alert dialog , you need to add the following code to it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      /*  builder.setMessage("Visit Be Developers.tech");
        builder.setTitle("Alert");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_24);//This line should be added

        builder.setPositiveButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

For more customization like adding list , choices take a look at
https://bedevelopers.tech/alert-dialog-in-android-show-alert-using-the-builder/

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setTitle("Alert");
***builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_24)***
builder.setPositiveButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```