# A customized Dialog is displaying misplaced contents

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

In the below posted code, is how I am customizing my `Dialog`. But the contents that should fill the `Dialog` are misplaced  or are not in its respective position of the `Dialog`. For an example, the word "Report" should be placed at the upper part of the `dialog` along with the `icon`, but as you see in the image, they are placed under the line that separated the upper part of the `title` and the `icon` and the rest of the `dialog`. how to correct it?

Please have a look at the image of the output and the code as well.

JavaCode:

```
Dialog reportAlertDialog = new Dialog(MeetingPointFix.this);
            LayoutInflater reportAlertDialogLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View reportAlertDialogInflatedView = reportAlertDialogLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.report_dialog, null);

            reportAlertDialog.setContentView(reportAlertDialogInflatedView);

            int [] viewsRefsIds = {R.id.reportLocNameValue, R.id.reportLocLatValue, R.id.reportLocLngValue, R.id.reportTimeValue,
                    R.id.reportDateValue, R.id.reportImgTitleValue, R.id.reportImgPathValue
            };
            TextView [] viewsVars = new TextView[viewsRefsIds.length];

            TextView reportAlertDialogMSG = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogMessageValue);
            TextView reportAlertDialogTitle = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogTitleValue);
            reportAlertDialogMSG.setText(REPORT_ALERT_DIALOG_MSG);
            reportAlertDialogTitle.setText(REPORT_ALERT_DIALOG_TITLE);

            for (int i=0; i<bundleVals.length; i++) {
                viewsVars[i] = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(viewsRefsIds[i]);
                viewsVars[i].setText(bundleVals[i]);
            }
            reportAlertDialog.show();
```

LogCat:

```
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673): Process: com.example.meetingpointlocator_03, PID: 5673
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673): java.lang.RuntimeException: The feature has not been requested
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDrawableState(PhoneWindow.java:3200)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setFeatureDrawableResource(PhoneWindow.java:1208)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at android.app.Dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Dialog.java:1049)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix$4.report(MeetingPointFix.java:296)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix$4.onClick(MeetingPointFix.java:240)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-24 10:35:32.357: E/AndroidRuntime(5673):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

OutPut:
[image]

Comment: This happens to those who like to do things **programmatically**, instead of using the **xml layouts**!

Comment: You are required to set the title and icon. You haven't done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the title to the alerdialog

```
 reportAlertDialog.setTitle(REPORT_ALERT_DIALOG_TITLE);// takes charactersequence as param
```

Similarly

```
 reportAlertDialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawabl‌​e.some_icon);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

You  don't need that Custom `ImageView` and `TextView` it can be removed if you don't want them to appear in the dialog content part.

Edit:

> The feature has not been requested

```
Dialog  dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON); // request the feature
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customlayout);
dialog.setTitle("My Title");
dialog.show();
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
// set the icson
```

Comment: I thought that my underlaying layout will fit the "dialog" as a whole! does that mean if i need create a layout.xml for the dialog title and another one for its body?sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @Amr no you don't require all those. just use `setTitle()` and `setIcon()` on the dialog object. And read the Dialog docs. I posted alertdialog link sorry

Comment: AlertDialog.setIcon() is not a available but AlertDialog.setTitle() is.Any idea why is that

Comment: @Amr its not alerdialog. Its a Custom Dialog

Comment: @Amr `AlertDialog` has `setIcon()`. but you have a Custom Dialog

Comment: @Amr you could use this `reportAlertDialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.some_icon);`

Comment: @Rughunandan this "reportAlertDialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawabl‌​e.some_icon)" causes the app to crash

Comment: @Amr and post the stacktrace

Comment: @Amr use alertdialog then you can use `setIcon`. No setIcon for Dialog

Comment: i tried to use alertdialog, but the problem is that eclipse complains about "AlertDialog reportDialog = new AlertDialog(MeetingPointFix.this);" and says "alertDailog(context) is not visible. i changed to be AlertDialog reportDialog = new AlertDialog(getapplicationcontext); but i receive the same error

Comment: no `getAppplicationContext()` use `ActivityContext`. ActivityName.this. Better post the stacktrace

Comment: please see the logcat output posted. there is no "ActivityContext" and "actvityName.this" is underscored with red squiggle

Comment: @Amr you are using alert dialog or dialog? Your code suggests you are using Dialog. And do you know what Activity Context is?

Comment: the posted logcat out put is based on using dialog. as i informed in my previous two comments, eclipse does not allow me to use alerDailog because it says" constructor is not visible when using getapplicationcontext or myactivivty.this

Comment: i just want to add an icon beside the title of the dialog."reportDialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.reporticon01);" causes the app to crash. and my underlaying layout of the dialog is only set for the body of the dialog and not for the title. every thing in my layout.xml appears in the dialog's body. without setting the title explicitly it, the upper part of the dialog, would be empty

Comment: @Amr that does not work. You have to remove that. use AlertDialog. I don't see a problem using alert dialog

Comment: @Amr check the edit it will work with custom dialog. Also using alert dialog should not be a problem

Comment: @Amr you set the custom layout to the dialog. Its the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AlertDialog.setIcon()` and `AlertDialog.setTitle()` for setting icon and title of the dialog.

Comment: I thought that my underlaying layout will fit the "dialog" as a whole! does that mean if i need create a layout.xml for the dialog title and another one for its body?sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: AlertDialog.setIcon() is not a available but AlertDialog.setTitle() is.Any idea why is that

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430253/how-to-set-icon-for-dialog-in-android